# Link thumbnail on Facebook for iOS is always small

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know why, but for my website, anytime i share a link on Facebook, the preview looks good on Facebook.com and older-smaller in iOS app (iPhone and iPad).

I use image that are 600 to 1500 width and 1.69:1 ratio (Facebook suggest 1.91:1). But nothing seems to work. The url debugger always tell me that everything is ok, but the preview on mobile still look ugly-old-and-small.

There is a solution for this problem?

Here is the url:
http://www.trailersland.com/trailer/hd-noah-trailer-internazionale-sottotitolato-in-italiano

Debug url:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trailersland.com%2Ftrailer%2Fhd-noah-trailer-internazionale-sottotitolato-in-italiano

Image Url:
http://images.chefilm.it/66658_rO_2.jpg

And here is some screenshot to give you the idea what problem is.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

This problem was reported as Bug on Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1410151209247136/

Comment: Same happening to me. Very annoying as we use the image size as described by Facebook